# How to make a click counter for another button function?

Tags: javascript, function, button, onclick, counter

I made a function that checks if an input number is equal to Math.random(). I want to make another function to check how many times the button was clicked before the user got the correct answer.

```js
function guess() {
  var x = document.getElementById('this').value;
  var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));

  if (x == y) {
    alert("Nice");
  } //correct answer
  else if (x > y) {
    alert("Lower");
  } else {
    alert("Higher");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="number" min=1 max=2 id="this">
  <button type="button" onclick="guess()">Check</button>
</body>
```

I expect to see the number of tries the number has done.

Comment: Do you realize that you're generating a new random number every time the user clicks the button? So the hints that popup are useless

Answer (score 2):

Taking into account Nick Parsons comment, I moved the number searched for out of the function. The counter also needs to be defined outside the function and incremented by one on each call. I also altered your code to give the number of attempts when guessed correctly.

```js
var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));
var counter = 0;

function guess() {
  var x = document.getElementById('this').value;
  counter += 1;
  
  if (x == y) {
    alert(`Nice. Took you ${counter} attempts`);
  } //correct answer
  else if (x > y) {
    alert("Lower");
  } else {
    alert("Higher");
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <input type="number" min=1 max=10 id="this">
  <button type="button" onclick="guess()"> Check </button>
</body>
```

Also the `max` on the number-input field was not right.

Answer (score 1):

Create a global variable (say, `counter`) intialized to zero, then increment it every time the button is clicked:

```
var counter = 0;

var y = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10));

function guess() {
  var x = document.getElementById('this').value;
  counter += 1;
  if (x == y) {
    alert("Nice. You've guessed it in " + counter + " tries.");
    counter = 0;
  } //correct answer
  else if (x > y) {
    alert("Lower");
  } else {
    alert("Higher");
  }
}
```

Although you didn't ask for it, note that I placed the initialization of `x` and `y` from outside the event handler function. If you put it inside, every time you click the button, `y` would be set to a *new* random number, which makes the hints useless (and I infer you didn't want to do that anyway).

Comment: Agree with the y but x needs to be inside otherwise the guess doesn't update.

Answer (score 0):

You must first declare a global variable to store click counter and every time that user try incorrect, increase the variable and finally if successful try then  alert it.